# Line's sum of 2 dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I'm writing a code that can read a data inside 2 dimensional array and then store the sum of each line in another 1 dimensional array.
This is the code I'm using:

```
n = 256
b = [[0]*n for p in range (n)]
line = []

for k in range(1,4,256):
   for j in range(1,256,1):
      line[k] = line[k] + b[j][k]
print line
```

But I always get this error: **list index out of range**

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `range(1,4,256)`.  This problem be much more naturally expressed with a list comprehension `[sum(subl) for subl in b]`

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, it's for k in range(1,4,1):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most importantly you need to define the list like you did with b because you can't access a value in a spot that doesn't exist.
Well it's basically a matrix with the zise of 256x256 so to fix this first you need to start from 0 and not 1 because you would miss the first 3 values, second in the line for k in range(1,4,256) you put the number 256 in the end which means that on the second run k would be equal to 257 and exit the loop.

*You can replace line[k] = line[k] + b[j][k] with line[k] += b[j][k]

So in the end the code would be as follows:

```
line = [n*[0]]
for k in range(0,256):
    for j in range(0,256):
        line[k] += b[j][k]
print line
```

Comment: in my code, I want to store the sum of each line values, in my case, k is for lines and j is for columns. I have 3 lines and 256 columns.
I want to store in line[] every sum of each line (the sum of 256 values)